# Make content scroll behind sticky header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a scroll area in which there are different headings which I want to be sticky, have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qzmgoLa/).

```css
.item{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:red;
    margin:3px 0;
}

.heading{
    position:sticky;
    top:0;
    height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-y:auto;height:300px;">
    <h3 class="heading">Heading 1</h3>
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <h3 class="heading">Heading 2</h3>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <h3 class="heading">Heading 3</h3>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="item">Item 9</div>
    <h3 class="heading">Heading 4</h3>
    <div class="item">Item 19</div>
    <div class="item">Item 11</div>
    <div class="item">Item 12</div>
</div>
```

[image: example]

As you can see every item is visible behind the headings. As in the fiddle, in my real application these heading elements are also transparent. So I need a way to make the items overflow right under each heading.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do... maybe the background color of the heading should hide the contents once they are scrolled under the heading >??

Comment: Yes, the headings should hide the items below them, but they have to be transparent, because in my application there is a background-image, so I can't use a color or anything like that

Comment: and the next level headings should not be allowed to be scrolled on top of previous level headings ?

Comment: have a look at this.. maybe this is what you want in your application actually...   https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_accordion_active

Comment: That's not the thing I want, sorry. If you have a look at the screenshot, I want the first item not to be visible above the bottomline of "Heading 1"

Answer (score 0):

Place `background:inherit` to heading and every wrapping element up to the element which has the image as backgrund. [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ifWbEMGt0KWkvoFrla1r?p=preview) [Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387442/hide-elements-behind-transparent-div-but-not-background)

Comment: I already tried what was suggested there, but it results in an undesired effect, see my updated fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see no update in your fiddle. It would be good to see the whole code with background img etc.

Comment: So you can't use `background-attachment: fixed;`?